# AngularX ngOnChange inside of ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, reactive-programming

I have control which builds form from json schema and propagate value as an object. 
This component is inside of other control who is setting json schema, and the problem is when I am changing input value `jsonSchema` i need to propagate new value (Since form is rebuild during jsonSchema value change) but i am getting error
`Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.` This is because on the begging form is valid since no fields are set but after settings jsonSchema with required fields form become an invalid.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'name',
  templateUrl: './json-schema-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./json-schema-form.component.css'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: JsonSchemaFormComponent,
    multi: true
  }, {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: JsonSchemaFormComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class JsonSchemaFormComponent implements OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  private propagateChange: Function = function (change) { };
  private propagateTouch: Function = function () { };
  @Input() jsonSchema: any;
  @Input() defaultValues: any;
  registerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  customProperties: any[];
  constructor() { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    return this.registerForm.valid ? null : { "json-form": true };
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {

  }

  public registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.propagateTouch = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.setupForm();
  }

  private setupForm() {
    var formData = {};
    this.registerForm.addControl("test", new FormControl("", [Validators.required]));
    this.propagateChange(this.registerForm.value);
  }
}
```

Temporary fix is that i propagate event with delay. But i dont like idea of any delays..

```
this.controlChanged
      .debounceTime(5)
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log("JsonSchemaFormComponent", this.registerForm);
        this.propagateChange(this.registerForm.value);
      });
    this.registerForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.controlChanged.next();
    });
```

I have reproduced this example. Open developer toolbars console then try to set any number in input

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZmYBiH6kciXqQXp2f3KU

Comment: Are you subscribing on `valueChanges` every `ngOnChanges`? Can you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: @yurzui I fixed that now its in constructor. to subscribe only once. Also let me update source code since problem is actually not in subscription but in propagating

Comment: @yurzui also i am thinking that problem is actually that this component is inside of other formgroup..

Comment: Where do you use `control.status` in your template?

Comment: @yurzui let me create a plankr

Comment: @yurzui i have added example

Comment: If you propagate changes in your parent form then you have to wait next tick. See one possible solution here https://plnkr.co/edit/342s6m1kDWEuUcgOaI7g?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui can you post it as a solution? For me it is still sounds like a bug. Because now i need to know that on onChanges event i need to change values in nex tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in comments because angular is built on unidirectional data flow you have to fire the next tick via `setTimeout` or this way:

```
const resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve(null);
...
resolvedPromise.then(() => {
   this.propagateChange(this.registerForm.value);
});
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/342s6m1kDWEuUcgOaI7g?p=preview)**

Comment: Using your solution i come out with a bit cleaner solution i think https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15217#issuecomment-287228219 :)

Comment: @Mohsen It is sad. Where is your plunker?)